# Firestore App Check not working with Xcode 13.3.1 and Firestore/Storage Rules

Tags: xcode, firebase

I Cannot figure out why AppCheck in Firebase is not allowing me permissions to Firestore when enforced.

I followed the docs and unenforced the app works fine. Enforced, and published to test flight with:
App Attest capability both on Xcode and FB Settings.
App Test environment set to production.
Removed Debug logic.

Before I published I updated the package manager and got a bunch of warnings from FB gRPC-core. not sure if whats going on.